# How to remove pink border around splash screen in corona sdk?

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

Corona labs added a splash screen in their recent daily builds, that can be removed by purchasing a plugin. The splash screen has a pink border in some devices, though.

How can i remove the pink border around splash screen in Corona SDK? Not the splash screen itself.

[image]

Comment: "purchase a plugin" is proper solution. I don't think it is on-topic to ask a questions how to hack different software.

Comment: i don't want to remove the splash, i want to remove the pink border, and who mentioned hacking?

Comment: I put so much time solving your last question and you have even bothered accepting the answer!

Comment: It looks like "magic purple" #ff00ff - "transparent" color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in Corona SDK daily build 2016.2955 and on, which you can download in the [Corona SDK daily builds download page](https://developer.coronalabs.com/downloads/daily-builds/). You have to be registered and logged in to see that page. You can see the notes for this build:

> Fix issue which caused magenta borders when displaying the Corona splash screen

It says it is fixed on iOS but the problem is gone in android devices as well.